# Passing JSON file as string in environment variable for composer airflow from terraform script

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating a composer from terraform where I want to pass a json as input variable

Terraform code:

```
software_config{
  env_variables{
   AIRFLOW_VAR_MYJSON ="{'__comment1__': 'This the global section', 'project_id':'testproject', 'gce_zone':'us-east1-c', 'gce_region':'us-east1','networkname':'vpc1', 'subnetwork':'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testproject/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/subnet1'}"
}
}
```

I am trying to read the value of AIRFLOW_VAR_MYJSON  in DAG , but it is not working as the value is not recognized as JSON.
I tried converting it and then deserializing it with following code:

```
JSONList = Variable.get("MYJSON")
jsonvar = json.dumps(JSONList)
setting_var = Variable.set("settings", jsonvar)
dag_config = Variable.get("settings", deserialize_json=True)
```

but it is not working.

I have also tried using

```
dag_config =json.loads(jsonvar)
```

then reading value as

```
project_id = dag_config["project_id"]
```

but I get error : "string indices must be integers"

Please suggest a way to resolve this.

NOTE : I know the gcloud command to set variables from json file but that is not working in my case as the project is in VPC and kubernetes clusters are giving timeout or handshake error, so I have ruled out use of this option

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

[Valid JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) can only be `"` not `'`. Try switching the quotes.

> A value can be a **string in double quotes**, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.

```
software_config{
  env_variables{
   AIRFLOW_VAR_MYJSON ="{\"__comment1__\": \"This the global section\", \"project_id\":\"testproject\", \"gce_zone\":\"us-east1-c\", \"gce_region\":\"us-east1\",\"networkname\":\"vpc1\", \"subnetwork\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testproject/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/subnet1\"}"
}
}
```

Or a little nicer way:

```
software_config {
  env_variables {
    AIRFLOW_VAR_MYJSON = jsonencode({
      "__comment1__" = "This the global section",
      "project_id" = "testproject",
      "gce_zone" = "us-east1-c",
      "gce_region" = "us-east1",
      "networkname" = "vpc1",
      "subnetwork" = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/testproject/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/subnet1",
    })
  }
}
```